# Slow Internet On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet

I'm running the newest version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP laptop dual-booting along with Windows 10.

On Windows, the Wi-Fi connection works as expected and is relatively fast, but on Ubuntu it's very slow and takes minutes just to load one webpage. What could be causing this? Could it be a driver issue, and if so how do I update it?

Feedback appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you list the model of HP laptop and/or the chipset of its wifi card?

Comment: The laptop is HP 255 G1 and the Wi-Fi adapter is Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn (I think? At least that's what Windows tells me)

Answer (score -1):

Connect to ethernet, and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

This command updates your system fully. That way, if there is a fix already in the new kernels (which get updated extremely frequently) you get it.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have access to direct connection to ethernet. I assume it's possible over Wi-Fi? But I'll try that. But would it make a difference considering I just recently installed Ubuntu with the latest .iso?

Comment: 16.04 is not the "latest" iso.  That's April 2016.

Comment: pauljohn32 However, it is LTS and more widely supported than 17.04 or 17.10, which are both getting to be end-of-life soon.